# I am trying to install ios-deploy on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.2 by running cnpm install -g ios-deploy and it end up with this error message:

Tags: appium-ios

> fangyongteng$ cnpm install -g ios-deploy Downloading ios-deploy to
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy_tmp Copying
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy_tmp/_ios-deploy@1.9.2@ios-deploy
>   to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy Installing ios-deploy's
>   dependencies to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/node_modules
>   scripts.preinstall ios-deploy@1.9.2  "./src/scripts/check_reqs.js &&
>   xcodebuild" stderr: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires
>   Xcode, but active

developer directory '`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`' is a command line tools instance

> Install fail! Error: Run "sh -c ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js &&
>   xcodebuild" error, exit code 1
>
> Error: Run "sh -c ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild" error,
>   exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.proc.on.code (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cnpm/node_modules/runscript/index.js:74:21)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5) npminstall version: 3.3.0 npminstall
>   args: /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.3.0_1/bin/node
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cnpm/node_modules/npminstall/bin/install.js
>   --china --userconfig=/Users/fangyongteng/.cnpmrc --disturl=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node --registry=http://registry.npm.taobao.org -g ios-deploy

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem, and my solution is use `sudo xcode-select --reset`

Answer (score 0):

I carried out this statement solves this problem: sudo xcode - select - switch/Applications/Xcode9.2 app/Contents/Developer